# Access to Reverse Shell from another network

Tags: reverse-shell

If when we have a reverse shell and get persistence and we try to access the compromised target from another network different from the one which we created the payload, is that access to the compromised target still possible or only from the network where the payload was created?

Comment: "and we try to access the compromised target" -- how would you do that? Reverse shells connect to ***you***, not the other way around. And it's not about where the payload was created, but the IP that was configured in the payload.

Comment: If you create an SSH tunnel from host A to host B, then it's possible for host B to access host A through reverse SSH tunneling.  This is useful if host A is behind a NAT device or firewall, which would normally prevent host B from accessing host A.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work for more info.